# How do I wire a 4-wire 220v cooktop to a 3 prong plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, cooktops

I just bought a new cooktop which comes with 4 exposed wires.

It also comes with a diagram on how to configure it using a NEMA 10-50p type plug -- which is great because that matches the type of socket that my kitchen has.

I find the diagram kind of sketchy tho, since it seemingly suggests connecting two of the wires to the same 'hot' prong and the N wire to the other hot prong. I´ll attach photos.

[image: diagram]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image: socket]

[image: wires]

So, I guess my main question is, is that diagram safe to follow? Should I just screw the red+black wires to that same prong?

Comment: Can you get us photos of the inside of the outlet box in the wall please?

Comment: Where are you located in the world?  That wiring diagram suggests that it's for a European style 240 volt system (single 240 volt hot + neutral and ground), while the outlet suggests a US style system (240 volts between the two hots + neutral and ground).

Comment: A NEMA 10-50 is **not great.** Hope that yours actually has a ground wire hiding in the box, or grounded metal conduit, and replace it with hardwiring or a NEMA 14-50 if that is the case. They've been banned in new work since the 1996 code cycle as the dead bodies keep piling up. "Grandfathering" means you're not required to rip it out (unless it was illegally installed "to match the cord on the stove"  (correct action being to rewire the stove for 4-wire service) in a house built or remodeled after the 1996 code went into effect) but ripping it out is indeed the right thing to do.

Comment: @Traveler it says both 50 Hz *and* 60 Hz, supporting [Manasseh's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/292902/6820).

Comment: What's the brand/model of the cook top?

Comment: This is a "burn your house down" kind of scenario. Don't wire that device up.

Answer (score 4):

Based on a number of clues, I suspect this is a device that is nominally designed for multiple locations (US/Canada, Europe, Asia) but actually certified to work properly in none of them.

NEMA 10-50 indicates OP is in US/Canada with either an old house (grandfathered) or an incorrect (but common) receptacle type. In the US and Canada, all equipment of this type needs to be either listed by a NRTL (e.g., UL, ETL) or be should be approved by the local jurisdiction.

Does the appliance have UL, ETL or similar listing?

*I didn't think so.*

Send it back.

Comment: Hi, I think I'll follow your (and most people's) advice and send it back. 
thanks everyone for you advice